# Insert dynamic id into api request link to display data

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my code, can't find a solution to insert the id of the recipes that I have into a new request to display the calories of the recipes into HTML. All I want is to somehow add a dynamic id instead of the static 634091 id over there into the API url, because if I send that request and refresh my page it will not display the calories in HTML because it will be another id generated from every refresh. If it is not clear I can provide additional information, thank you so much for your time.

**js:**

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  const api_url_calories =
    "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/634091/nutritionWidget.json";

  // Defining async function
  async function getapi(url) {
    // Storing response
    const response = await fetch(url);

    // Storing data in form of JSON
    var data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    data.calories.forEach((obj) => {
      /*
        create new DOM elements
    */
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      let calories = document.createElement("p");

      div.append(calories);

      /*
        assign content from api data
    */

      calories.innerHTML = obj.calories;

      /*
        add to DOM
    */
      displayRecipes.append(div);
    });

    //   if (response) {
    //     console.log("data here");
    //   }
  }

  getapi(api_url_calories);
}, 100);
```

**HTML:**

```html
<body>
    <div id="displayRecipes"></div>
</body>
```

The response from the api for the calories information is this:

```js
{
    "calories": "316",
    "carbs": "49g",
    "fat": "12g",
    "protein": "3g",
    "bad": [
        {
            "name": "Calories",
            "amount": "316",
            "indented": false,
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 15.84
        },
```

js from the recipes request where the id comes from

```
const api_url =
  "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?number=3";

// Defining async function
async function getapi(url) {
  // Storing response
  const response = await fetch(url);

  // Storing data in form of JSON
  var data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  data.recipes.forEach((obj) => {
    /*
        create new DOM elements
    */
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    let image = new Image();
    let cuisines = document.createElement("p");
    let id = document.createElement("p");

    div.append(h1);
    div.append(image);
    div.append(cuisines);
    div.append(id);

    /*
        assign content from api data
    */
    h1.innerHTML = obj.title;
    image.src = obj.image;
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      cuisines.innerHTML = obj.cuisines;
    }
    // cuisines.innerHTML = obj.cuisines[0];
    id.innerHTML = obj.id;

    /*
        add to DOM
    */
    displayRecipes.append(div);
  });
  //   if (response) {
  //     console.log("data here");
  //   }
}
// Calling that async function
getapi(api_url);
```

How the recipes data looks like, it has an id key.

```
"recipes": [
        {
            "vegetarian": false,
            "vegan": false,
            "glutenFree": false,
            "dairyFree": false,
            "veryHealthy": false,
            "cheap": false,
            "veryPopular": false,
            "sustainable": false,
            "weightWatcherSmartPoints": 1,
            "gaps": "no",
            "lowFodmap": false,
            "aggregateLikes": 11,
            "spoonacularScore": 21.0,
            "healthScore": 1.0,
            "creditsText": "Foodista.com – The Cooking Encyclopedia Everyone Can Edit",
            "license": "CC BY 3.0",
            "sourceName": "Foodista",
            "pricePerServing": 12.65,
            "extendedIngredients": [
                {
                    "id": 1123,
                    "aisle": "Milk, Eggs, Other Dairy",
                    "image": "egg.png",
                    "consistency": "solid",
                    "name": "eggs",
                    "nameClean": "egg",
                    "original": "3 eggs, slightly beaten",
                    "originalString": "3 eggs, slightly beaten",
                    "originalName": "eggs, slightly beaten",
                    "amount": 3.0,
                    "unit": "",
                    "meta": [
                        "slightly beaten"
                    ],
                    "metaInformation": [
                        "slightly beaten"
                    ],
                    "measures": {
                        "us": {
                            "amount": 3.0,
                            "unitShort": "",
                            "unitLong": ""
                        },
                        "metric": {
                            "amount": 3.0,
                            "unitShort": "",
                            "unitLong": ""
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Please revert your edit so we can still see the question

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with concatenation:

```js
const recipe_id = "YOUR_DESIRED_ID";
const api_url_calories =
    "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/" + recipe_id + "/nutritionWidget.json";
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and answer. I tried this but I get the error recipe_id is not defined. The id of the recipes are generated random by the API so if I add a recipe id there it is not going to work because when I refresh both ids will not match. How can I manage to insert that recipe_id to be like the one that the API provides? Thanks a lot

Comment: Then it would be a good idea to edit your question and add the code that generates the id...

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your answer. I added the code from where I receive the recipes data from API and also the structure of it, to see it has an id key and to understand better what I am trying to do above. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's still not clear when and where these js code blocks are called. And it's strange that there are two functions `getapi()`. Furthermore: Shouldn't it be `id.innerHTML = obj.extendedIngredients.id;`?